# Simplify sum of products of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there a way to simplify :
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose i} {m \choose i}$?

Comment: If $m=n$, we get $\binom{2n}n$

Comment: What's the value of $m$?

Comment: @Icycarus what do you mean?
m and n are random integers.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt whats about case $m \neq n$?

Comment: @Nathan Beats me.  I haven't seen this particular problem before, and it doesn't look very interesting to solve IMO.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You have seen it before, it is the Vandermonde convolution identity with the first term missing.$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n,i} \binom{m,i} =\binom{n+m,n}-1$ & it is very interesting IMHO :-)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit :-) Ah, I did not recognize.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It was the removal of the first term that got you ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Nah, I just don't do combinatoric sums all the time.  Its been a while for me.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855538/evaluate-sum-k-0n-n-choose-km-choose-k-for-a-given-n-and-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n\leq m$ then $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \binom m{k}$ counts all the ways to swap items between piles of $n$ and $m$ items; by doing counting selections of items in each pile to swap for each swap size ($k\in \{0..n\}$).   Also when $n>m$ it counts the same by the convention that $\binom {m}{r}=0$ for all $r>m$.

We could do this by gathering all the items into one pile of $n+m$ and count ways to sort them back into piles of $n$ and $m$ items.   This is $\binom {n+m}m$

Eg $\binom{5}2=10$

Thus as the count of ways to perform the same task must be the same:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k\binom m k~=~ \binom {n+m}n ~=~ \binom {m+n}m ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^m \binom m k\binom n k$$

$~\\~\\~\\~\\~$

---

NB: Your series is indexed $1$, so does not include the term $\binom n0\binom m0$ which is 1.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom n k\binom m k~=~ \binom {n+m}n-1 ~=~ \binom {m+n}m -1~=~ \sum_{k=1}^m \binom m k\binom n k$$

Comment: Awesome interpretation, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

prove with induction that we get $$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{i}={\frac { \left( m+1 \right)  \left( n+m \right) !}{ \left( m+1
 \right) !\,n!}}-1
$$

Comment: Thanks, right side can be simplified to:

$\frac{(n+m)!}{m!n!}-1 = {{n+m} \choose {m}} - 1$.

I am wondering how you come up with this right side?

Comment: i have this problem on my PC! i'm working with my students on combinatorics

Comment: The result on your PC can simplify.

Comment: ok i will note this thank you for the hint

Comment: Is there a way to came to the right side if a have no idea about how it looks?

Comment: Prof. Tutschke always say: try a number example to find a formula